# How do I eliminate this huge unwanted margin between two rows of flex items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex{
  min-height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content:center;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-items: center;
  
 background: red;
}
  
.coloring {
  background:#CCC;
  border-radius:7px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.Projects{
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.Tribute{
  order: 2;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.Portfolio{
  order: 3;
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">

   <div class="coloring Projects">Projects</div>
   <div class="coloring Tribute">Tribute</div>
   <div class="coloring Portfolio">Portfolio</div>

</section>
```

When you narrow the screen there is going to be 3 rows and now there are 2 such huge unwanted margins. I don’t know what to do. If I eliminate `align-items: center` the boxes will fill the entire page, but that is not what I want.

Comment: Please describe (in English, or with a mockup) the appearance you _do_ want.  I can think of several different changes that would eliminate the gaps between the flex items, but they all have different side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aligning *between* multiple *flex lines* is handled by the [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) property - try `align-content: center` to eliminate the *margins* - see demo below:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  background: red;
}
.coloring {
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.Projects {
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}
.Tribute {
  order: 2;
  flex: 1 1;
}
.Portfolio {
  order: 3;
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
  <div class="coloring Projects">Projects</div>
  <div class="coloring Tribute">Tribute</div>
  <div class="coloring Portfolio">Portfolio</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

only you have to remove

min-height from .flex class